# html form background overlay

Tags: html, css

I have this css code:

```
#ticket {
        background:rgba(139,137,137,0.7);
    }
```

my form has an ID of `ticket`

this is showing a background on the form however the text inputs, text areas and select inputs and showing "on top" of the background

how can i make the background display on top of all elements?

Comment: Why would a **background** show on **top** of anything?

Comment: You can use pseudo (Before/After) to achieve what you want

Comment: @Paulie_D more of an overlay not background

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
    #ticket{
    display: block;
    width: 200px;
    height: 100px;
    background: green;  
    position: relative;
}

#ticket:before {
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
    background:rgba(139,137,137,0.7);
    content: "";
    top:0;
    left:0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    z-index:9999;
 }
```

**[DEMO HERE](https://jsfiddle.net/gun82rgy/)**

Comment: thats great - i just made some changes. see here: https://jsfiddle.net/gun82rgy/1/ is there a way i can make the JQueryPopup div display over the overlay?

Comment: That´s another question...i advise to put another question

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, you want the input elements to be placed on the form, and still be able to see the background colour of the form?

```
#ticket input,
#ticket textarea,
#ticket select {
    background:transparent;
}
```

This will the backgrounds of the elements transparent so you can see the forms' background.

```css
#ticket {
  background: rgba(139, 137, 137, 0.7);
}
#ticket input,
#ticket textarea,
#ticket select {
  background: transparent;
}
```

```html
<form id="ticket">
  <input>
  <textarea col="10" row="10"></textarea>
  <select>
    <option>Gender</option>
    <option>Male</option>
    <option>Female</option>
  </select>
</form>
```